# how to save the value of ESP during a function call

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have a problem with the below code:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    __asm {
        mov eax, a;
        mov ebx, b;
        push[eax];
        push[ebx];
        pop[eax];
        pop[ebx];
    }
}
int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 6;
    printf("a: %d\tb: %d\n", a, b);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a: %d\tb: %d\n", a, b);
}
```

I am running this code in visual studio and when I run this, it says:

> Run-Time check failure- The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you inspect the disassembly that resulted from the build of this?

Comment: It looks to me like it'd work fine if it was inline, but as is, it looks like a call and return, but there isn't even a ret instruction.

Comment: Which compiler/environnment/OS/IDE etc.  do you use? Please [edit] and make that clear. Also don't describe stuff in your comments but [edit] and show them in the question. For example the complete disassembly of your code would be very helpful.

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski: It's not `__declspec(naked)`, there shouldn't be a `ret` inside the asm statement.  Adding one would crash, likely popping the saved EBP instead of a return address into EIP.  Or in this case the saved EBX, since `swap` uses a call-preserved register (EBX) for no reason so the compiler has to save it around the asm statement as well: https://godbolt.org/z/M1541Kaz9

Answer (score 5):

To answer the title question: make sure you balance pushes and pops.    (Normally getting that wrong would just crash, not return with the wrong ESP). If you're writing a whole function in asm make sure `ret 0` or `ret 8` or whatever matches the calling convention you're supposed to be using and the amount of stack args to pop (e.g. caller-pops cdecl `ret 0` or callee-pops stdcall `ret n`).

---

Looking at the compiler's asm output (e.g. [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFxtpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BflzllWk1dQQFYZHREi0KtfWNWQNDXcE9xX1cXACUtqhexMjsHABuqHjoANQKAO5MCRDBBABUO0ykO6cXEXM7JgDsVhoAgjufOwD630wKLEeLxM7y%2BYJ2LFQ6x2mCYqmuTBMAGZXh9wZ9IdDMBF4TsIsjUejPgkvAoEI8AKwWWGqEwUgAiBJBaPRJLJlOpOLpjJRzKJOySCQ5NO5TNBRMFwq5DLFLKBjPezwVb2Zm22e0OCW%2BmJOgguVxuerxD2ehK%2Bv3%2BgNNfKJmJhcIRNvRduxuPx4udUJhyFxdOpcNFHvBLvQvqprsDcrBdr9IoZ10woadwa9sel9ITPuTSuZOcV%2BZVZiRwWQ3iwjyRbkG%2BFQADoEMjsLn3qcIUxghATcCg62mBX6TskdcIv2dgA2WVghLEU5UCDmMxMECPMwU9B0twECLL8xrjcMBcI4dzSdfA5HedmMcG8xj%2B6n4kzwRzhdLld7imb7fv9efg9lS5j1lJUOAWWhOApXg/A4LRSFQTg3Gsaw9iWFZMBXJEeFIAhNFAhYAGsQApDR9E4SQoNwuDOF4BQQBInCYNA0g4FgJA0BYBI6GichKHYzj6BiUtvhCfZviReIsHWPBVgANTwTB9gAeQSRhOCwmhaAIaJaIgbdGNICJgjqABPNTeEM5hiGMxSIm0TAHDM0h2LYQRFIYWhTP0rAWEMYBxC8vBiHsxx1kwWj9MwVR7K8LTHNOCpKNoPAImIEyPCwSiCBnFgzIWKgDGABQ5IU5TVO4Xh%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUfTdBaAwjBQJDLH0ZLaMgBZUASKpwoAWkU2C7GCtIXAYdxPCafxZu6IoSmyZJUgEEZmkSdaqmW3oYgGCopoEDphnm0ZWhO6pxn26ZDtscYtr0QZOju1b5kWZZVgkMCIIo/T4I4HZVAADjHCEFHWZAdnWLgAE5aykHYIAAdQASVCbAHggXBCBIDD5l4BitDmAiiJI8COHI0hoNgoGaLo7DcLJ0iODMAH6eo5nGNZ0LiBSZxJCAA) or locally) reveals the problem: **different operand-sizes for push vs. pop**, MSVC not defaulting to `dword ptr` for pop.

```
; MSVC 19.14 (under WINE) -O0

_a$ = 8                                       ; size = 4
_b$ = 12                                                ; size = 4
void swap(int *,int *) PROC                             ; swap
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    ebx                       ; save this call-preserved reg because you used it instead of ECX or EDX
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
        mov     ebx, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
        push    DWORD PTR [eax]
        push    DWORD PTR [ebx]
        pop     WORD PTR [eax]
        pop     WORD PTR [ebx]
        pop     ebx
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
void swap(int *,int *) ENDP
```

This code would just crash, with `ret` executing while ESP points to the saved EBP (pushed by `push ebp`).  Presumably Visual Studio passes addition debug-build options to the compiler so it does more checking instead of just crashing?

Insanely, MSVC compiles/assembles `push [reg]` to `push dword ptr` (32-bit operand-size, ESP-=4 each), but `pop [reg]` to `pop word ptr` (16-bit operand-size, ESP+=2 each)

It doesn't even warn about the operand-size being ambiguous, unlike good assemblers such as NASM where `push [eax]` is an error without a size override.  (`push 123` of an immediate always defaults to an operand-size matching the mode, but `push`/`pop` of a memory operand usually needs a size specifier in most assemblers.)

**Use `push dword ptr [eax]` / `pop dword ptr [ebx]`**

---

Or since you're using EBX anyway, not limiting your function to just the 3 call-clobbered registers in the standard 32-bit calling conventions, use registers to hold the temporaries instead of stack space.

```
void swap_mov(int* a, int* b) {
    __asm {
        mov eax, a
        mov ebx, b
        mov ecx, [eax]
        mov edx, [ebx]
        mov [eax], edx
        mov [ebx], ecx
    }
}
```

(You don't need `;` empty comments at the end of each line.  The syntax inside an `asm{}` block is MASM-like, not C statements.)